# Is it possible to statically link Qt::phonon on windows?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, phonon

Because of the dependency on DirectShow on windows, is it possible to use a static Qt with my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you link Qt statically and want to distribute your application, you will most likely require a commercial license. The LGPL license (using Qt for free) in practice mandates that you link Qt dynamically.